# ffmpeg libswresample.so.2 needed by libavcodec.so not found

Tags: ffmpeg

I have locally built ffmpeg library, but I am unable to link them in my program. 
I have tried CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH, but libswresample still cannot be found.
Strangely all the libraries libswresample, libavcodec etc etc are all in the same folder ( /local/git/PSG/libs/ffmpeg/../ffmpeg-install/lib/ ) . libavcodec is found, but not the libswresample.

So, I fail to understand why is gcc complaining?

I am using target_link_libraries(  ) to link the ffmpeg libraries.
What am I doing wrong?

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libswresample.so.2, needed by /local/git/PSG/libs/ffmpeg/../ffmpeg-install/lib/libavcodec.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

Comment: whats the difference between libavresample and libswresample? Maybe thats the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the libswresample.so.2 was taken from the system path. Unfortunately, all the libs generated by ffmpeg have to be explicitly linked in the target_link_libraries(). By explicitly giving the absolute path of libswresample for example by

```
find_library(libswresample_path NAMES libswresample PATH "the/path/to/your/libresample"),
```

the problem was solved

Comment: The same problem is also for me) I used a shared object locally built, but it depends of other libraries which are in the system path...